# Using OpenBSD /usr/libexec/auth/login_* from command line or other program

Tags: login, openbsd, authorization, yubikey

This may be an x-y problem and please feel free to point me in other directions as well.

I'm trying to write a login mechanism to dovecot's passdb, using either a Lua plugin or a CheckPassword program. The end goal is to be able to use a yubikey OTP specifically for dovecot, rather than mandating yubikey for all login as a user.

I found that the facilities available in `/usr/libexec/auth` seems usable. Specifically, I can call `/usr/libexec/auth/login_yubikey -d username` and get a password prompt. The program will print `authorize` to the terminal and exit with a 0 status on successful authorization.

Now, using these facilities from another program seems difficult. The `login_*` facilities use `readpassphrase(3)` that does not read from `stdin`, but rather from `/dev/tty` (and the difference here eludes me, I must confess).

How can I call the `/usr/libexec/auth/login_*` facilities supplying a password, rather than prompting the user for one?

If this is not possible, how can I authorize a given password or key for a user from a program?

Comment: Isn't the point with a Yubikey that a user has to physically touch it to provide the stored key?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is.